# sorting of dates and string simulteneously for same column in Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, date-sorting

I want to make a custom sort in such a way that , the date column if contains string insted of date then ignore it while sorting but the string should be shown on the datatable.

```
      "aoColumnDefs": [
                       { "sType": "currency", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
                       { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]}
                       ],
```

column 1 contains both dates and string formats and datatable is currently sorting it by alphabetical order and not by date.